# Blue British Passport Renewal

Tags: uk-citizens

Can the blue British passport be renewed? It's written British subject on national status. It belongs to my dad, I want a British passport for myself.

Comment: You don't need to renew his passport in order to register or apply for British nationality.

Comment: There's a little information [here](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/british-subject)

Answer (score 2):

The British passport has been the standard red one since 1989, this is the current biometric one, introduced in 2006:

[image: Red Passport with chip]

You don't get the blue one anymore (up to 1988).

Comment: Minor nitpick: The blue passport was issued between 1920 and 1988. Then burgundy was introduced in 1989. Your image is the biometric passport introduced in the 90's.

Comment: @Patrick, no need for thanks.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Patrick - feel free to accept the answer if you're happy 